# Ubuntu 15.10 Shutdown freeze

Tags: shutdown

Desktop computer, Intel motherboard installed Ubuntu 15.10, when I shutdown, it almost freeze. 
It working on Windows. 
How can I do? thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "almost freeze" ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is Desktop, please just add the model of the motherboard and put more information. If it is working on Windows, check the operating system itself.

Comment: freeze is mean hang-up. sorry, I know English a little. Motherboard is Intel DP35DP.